.NET 8 build issue - The analyzer assembly references version '4.5.0.0' of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version '4.3.0.0'
I recently upgraded my C# class library to .NET 8.0 and I started getting the error mentioned in the title. My Visual Studio version is 17.11.3
These are the compiler errors I am getting:

List of SDKs that I have installed:

Here is how my project XML file:

I checked here, here and here and I tried fixes that were mentioned there.
Fixes I tried:

Adding global.json which looks like this:



I also tried adding BuildWithNetFrameworkHostedCompiler to my project XML as shown above.

Apart from these, I also tried closing Visual Studio, deleting bin, obj and .vs folders and reopening it again but still the errors persists.
Any idea how can I fix these errors?

The project file isn't JSON - it's XML.

@marc_s Thanks for pointing that out, its fixed

Have you tried upgrading VS?

Also why do you have both net48 and .NET 8 and linux RID?

Here is a post with similar issue Issue Link

You specified both net4.8 and net8.0. Did you update your reference to net8.0?
